# Net::Telnet using getline() or getlines() not getting all lines

Tags: perl, telnet

If I telnet using my terminal window to the device and enter `show` which prints config it prints certain number of lines and `-- more --` in the bottom, you can press Return or Space on the keyboard a few times to get the rest of the command until it is all shown on screen, you know how it is.

With

```
$t->print('show');
```

Problem is neither

```
while (my $line = $t->getline()) {
    print $line;
}
```

or

```
my @lines = $t->getlines(All => 0); # or All => 1
```

gives me all lines, just the starting few as with the terminal window.

I cant use `cmd()` or `Expect` or `Net::OpenSSH` on that box (the machine where the script runs, im not talking about the device), no gcc and has a crippled package manager. (Read: can't install `IO::Pty`)

What can I do to get the rest of the output of the command?

Comment: The question still stands, I had to go around the problem by finding a command that returns a much smaller section of the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that `show` you use hasn't an option to turn off its paging, waiting for a keypress after each page, you have to `->print('')` at appropriate times, therewith sending the continuation characters.

Comment: Forgot I had this question open heh. Yes that did it on some of the problematic devices, sometimes I had to send `""` some times `" "` (space..) after a brief `sleep()` on my end, on others even that didn't work but its better than nothing.